# How to solve uiautomator 502 BadGateWay Error

Tags: python, tkinter, android-uiautomator, bad-gateway, http-status-code-502

It works on my computer, but I deployed it as an exe program through pyinstaller, but it doesn't work.

```
[D 230621 15:25:00 __init__:661] [pid:14580] [ce12160cfb12c03304] kill process(ps): uiautomator
[D 230621 15:25:02 __init__:391] [pid:14580] [ce12160cfb12c03304] Install app-uiautomator.apk
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "uiautomator2\__init__.py", line 486, in _jsonrpc_retry_call
    File "uiautomator2\__init__.py", line 519, in _jsonrpc_call
uiautomator2.exceptions.GatewayError: (<Response [502]>, 'gateway error, time used 0.0s')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    File "mobile_like.py", line 69, in main
    File "uiautomator2\utils.py", line 114, in __call__
    File "uiautomator2\_selector.py", line 314, in wait
    File "uiautomator2\__init__.py", line 479, in __call__
    File "uiautomator2\__init__.py", line 488, in _jsonrpc_retry_call
    File "uiautomator2\__init__.py", line 640, in reset_uiautomator
    File "uiautomator2\__init__.py", line 668, in _force_reset_uiautomator_v2
    File "uiautomator2\__init__.py", line 392, in _setup_uiautomator
    File "uiautomator2\__init__.py", line 824, in push
OSError: file 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI214802/uiautomator2/assets/app-uiautomator.apk' not found
```

I thought it was a network problem, so I tried to manipulate proxies, etc., but it still doesn't work